# limit of $\ln x + (x+1)/x$ as $x$ approaches $o$

Tags: limits, functions

I want to establish monotone intervals of function $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $f(x)=(x+1)\ln x$ using its first derivative. I proved that the first derivative of $f$ is an injective function and I want  to see if $\lim f'(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ multiplied by $\lim f'(x)$ as $x$ approaches $1$ is negative, that would mean the equation f'(x)=0 has at least one solution in $(0,1)$, and because $f'$ is injective there would be exactly one solution in $(0,1)$. Then I would be able to establish monotone intervals of $f$, even without knowing when $f'(x)=0$, I'll just name the solution '$y$'. But first I have to know if it there is only one solution y, and I don't know what is the limit of $\ln x + (x+1)/x$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: No time to work up a rigorous proof, but $\ln x$ diverges more slowly than $1/x$, so the result is $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

For your limit:

$$\ln(x) + \frac{x+1}{x} = 1 + \frac{1 + x \ln(x)}{x} \\
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln(x) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln(x) + \frac{x+1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 + \frac{1}{x} = +\infty.$$

For the stuff about monotonicity:

The function $g(x)=x \ln(x)$ is minimized when $x=e^{-1}$, where it is equal to $-e^{-1}$. You can see this because $g'(x)=\ln(x)+1$, which is zero when $x=e^{-1}$. Taking another derivative, you get $g''(x)=1/x>0$, so the critical point is a local minimum. This minimum is in fact global, because $g''(x)>0$ for *all* $x$.

Since $e^{-1}<1$, the numerator is positive for all $x>0$, so your function is positive for every $x>0$.

Comment: Ian, I believe your answer is unsufficient. How do you know xln(x) is minimized at x=-e^-1?

Comment: The derivative of $x\ln{x}$ is $\ln{x}+1$. Set it equal to $0$, and you find $x_{min}=e^{-1}$.

Comment: @Ferris I added some discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $f(x)=(x+1)\ln x$ is
$$
f'(x)=\ln x+\frac{x+1}{x}=\ln x+ 1 +\frac{1}{x}
$$
The second derivative is
$$
f''(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x-1}{x^2}
$$
which shows $f'(x)$ has a minimum at $1$; since
$$
f'(1)=2>0
$$
we can say that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$. Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing.

Note that $f'$ is *not* injective. Indeed
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\ln x+1}{x}+1=\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty
$$

[image]

[image]

The same with GeoGebra

[image]

Comment: What software is that?

Comment: @Demosthene It's Grapher, bundled with Mac OS X. I find it easier to use than GeoGebra.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Letting $t=\dfrac1x$ we have $~\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\bigg(\ln x+\frac1x\bigg)~=~\lim_{t\to\infty}(t-\ln t),~$ which is trivial.

Comment: how about $\lim_{x\to0^+}\bigg(\ln x+\frac1x\bigg)$ ? Note that $\ln x$ "is" not defined for $x<0$.